# Viewport seems to be slightly offscreen in fullscreen

Tags: java, opengl, ubuntu, fullscreen, jogl

In an OpenGL program I have a Camera object that sets up the projection matrix to be centered on a sprite.  It worked fine until I went into fullscreen mode, there I noticed the object I focused on was off center.  After messing around with my resolution I noticed that 4:3 resolutions don't have this problem(I was originally at 1680x1050) and then I found the following.

1280x1024: object is centered.
1280x960: object is centered.
1280x720: object is not centered and the entire viewport seems to have shifted left.  That is, when I move my mouse left it seems to move off screen a few inches and there is a black region on the right of my screen where nothing is drawn and my mouse won't move into.

Has anyone had a problem like this?  I'm on Ubuntu if that's significant.

Answer (score 1):

Are you accounting for the aspect ratio when setting up your projection matrix ?

[This tutorial](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Positioning/Tut04%20Aspect%20of%20the%20World.html) might be a useful read if not.

Here is my own version (in python but it should be trivial to translate to java) if having a code sample helps; initPerspectiveMatrix takes an aspect ratio, i.e. height/width.

```
def calcFrustumScale(fov):
    return (1.0 / np.tan(np.deg2rad(fov) / 2.0))

def initPerspectiveMatrix(aspectRatio = 1.0):
    scale = calcFrustumScale(60)
    ARscale = scale*aspectRatio
    near = 0.5
    far = 1000.0
    perspMx = np.array([[ARscale,  0.0 ,          0.0         ,            0.0         ],
                       [  0.0  , scale,          0.0         ,            0.0         ],
                       [  0.0  ,  0.0 , (near+far)/(near-far), (2*near*far)/(near-far)],
                       [  0.0  ,  0.0 ,         -1.0         ,            0.0         ]], dtype='float32')
```

Comment: I'm using glOrtho to set up my perspective.  At every iteration the camera calls glOrtho(objectCenter.x-80, objectCenter.x+80, objectCenter.y-50, objectCenter.y+50, -1, 1)(assuming 16:10 view ratio), and everytime the window gets resized I call glViewport(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight).  Am I missing anything?

Comment: I'm not familiar with glOrtho (I'm still learning OpenGL and I decided to go with 3.3 core so glOrtho, glFrustum, etc. are deprecated) but from reading the documentation, it seems like that would work for a 16:10 aspect ratio so I'm at a loss. Could it be that there already is something else on the matrix stack before glOrtho ? Or that you're not in the right matrix mode ?

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that your monitor is connected through VGA, and is not correctly calibrated for that resolution. So the monitor shifts the display output.

Possible solutions include:

- recalibrate your monitor (either automatically or manually, either from the monitor controls or the OS control, if available)
- switch the connection to a digital one (say DVI or HDMI).